# Swift - How do I display portions of an hour?

Tags: swift

I have a label that I'm updating every second which shows the hours with 100ths of an hour("1.67", etc.). I'm trying to get it to show correctly, but having trouble.

```
    second = 781

    let timeWorked = Float(second/3600)

    let timeWorkedInHours = (String(format:"%.02f", timeWorked))

    timeWorkedLabel.text = "\(timeWorkedInHours)"
```

I've tried a few things, but nothing that has worked yet. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your `second` is defined as `Int`. Define it as `Double` instead. Then you can get rid of the `Float` cast too:

```
var second: Double = 0
// ...
let timeWorked = second / 3600.0
```

Comment: You nailed it. Thank you.